# Replace the first and last symbol in a string

Tags: java, string

I have an input string

```
[N-[3-(1,3-ChemComp-2-yl)-6]-(compound-2]
```

I want the output as

```
N-[3-(1,3-ChemComp-2-yl)-6]-(compound-2
```

That is I want to remove the first occurance of **[** and the last occurance of **]**. I Tried using `str.replace()` but it replaces all the instances of the character. While `replaceFirst` only replaces character and it doesn't allow me enter the symbol **[**.

How do I remove the first **[** and the last **]** of my input string in java?

Comment: The question is somewhat ambiguous. The title states: _Replace the first and last symbol in a string_ - which is clear. But the body of the question states: _remove the first occurrence of `[` and the last occurrence of `]`_ - which is also clear, but clearly different from (more specific than) the title (because it suggests the first `[` may not be the first character of the string). And the example given in the question matches the title more closely than the description in the body. A clarification would help.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `substring` method

```java
String s = "[N-[3-(1,3-ChemComp-2-yl)-6]-(compound-2]";
String r = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
System.out.println(r);
```